# Zen HTML + Textmate

Tags: textmate

I've installed the [Zen Coding HTML textmate](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) bundle, but for certain shortcuts I'm getting both the inbuild TextMate bundle and the Zen HTML option. e.g. if I type link:style and hit tab I get two options.

How can I easily disable the inbuilt textmate html bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bundle Editor (Bundles > Bundle Editor), click "Filter List..." in the bottom left, and uncheck the HTML bundle

Answer (score 2):

To do the same in [E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) (a Windows editor with Textmate Bundles compatibility) you can do the following:

- Open the Bundles Manager [**Bundles** > **Edit Bundles** > **Manage Bundles**]
- Find the HTML bundle and click Delete

You can also easily install the Zen Coding, Zen HTML and Zen CSS bundles via the Bundles Manager.